# How to replace NaN values in a column A with respect to average value that is related to column B?

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on famous [Titanic dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic).
Am trying to fill the `X.Age.isna()` NaN values with `Avg_Age_byTitle`,which i have calculated using `X.groupby('Name').mean()['Age']`

```
Avg_Age_byTitle =
    Name
     Capt            70.000000
     Col             58.000000
     Don             40.000000
     Dr              42.000000
     Jonkheer        38.000000
     Lady            48.000000
     Major           48.500000
     Master           4.574167
     Miss            21.773973
     Mlle            24.000000
     Mme             24.000000
     Mr              32.368090
     Mrs             35.898148
     Ms              28.000000
     Rev             43.166667
     Sir             49.000000
     the Countess    33.000000
    Name: Age, dtype: float64
```

I tried this `X.Age[Avg_Age_byTitle[X.Name[ X.Age.isna()]]]` which returns `series` with Age as index and NaN as values. what's that am doing wrong?

Comment: can you just post a sample of the data and expected? what is column B? pclass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks All.
Solution:

```
X.Age = X.groupby(['Name']).Age.apply(lambda X : X.fillna(X.mean()))
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you need:

```
df['Age'] = df.groupby('Pclass')['Age'].apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean())).round(1)
```

this fills the NaN in Age based on the average of groups of `Pclass`.

Comment: Hi @anky_91 I think you did not understand the question. am trying to fill the NaN values using averaged age of the title that NaN belongs to.

Comment: @AmarP. "am trying to fill the NaN values using averaged age of the title" so based on group of anything or entire series average?

Answer (score 0):

Given that **X** and **Avg_Age_byTitle** both have **Name** as index, you can try:

```
    X[['Age']] = X[['Age']].fillna(Avg_Age_byTitle)
```

Comment: actually X has a integer(0 to N-1) as index and Avg_Age_byTitle has index of Name  as written above..